# How can I group a Pandas DataFrame by Local Minima?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Originally, I had a `Pandas DataFrame` that consists of two columns `A (for x-axis values)` and `B (for y-axis values)` that are plotted to form a simple `x-y coordinate graph`. The data consisted of a few peaks, where the peaks all occurred at the same `y-axis` value with the same increments. Thus, I was able to do the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/_______/Desktop/Data Packets/Cycle Data.csv')

nrows = int(df['B'].max() * 2) - 1

alphabet: list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
groups = df.groupby(df.index // nrows)
for (frameno, frame) in groups:
    frame.to_csv("/Users/_______/Desktop/Cycle Test/" + alphabet[frameno] + "%s.csv" % frameno, index=False)
```

The above code parses the large cycle data file into many data files of the same size, since the local minima and maxima of each cycle is the same.

However, I want to be able to parse a data file that has arbitrary peaks and minima. I can't split the large data file simultaneously because each data file is a different size. Here is an example illustration:[image]

Edit: sample data (`A` is x-axis, `B` is y-axis):

```
data = {'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26], 'B': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 3, 1, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 6, 8, 6, 4, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Edit 2: different sample data (`Displacement` goes from 1 to 50 back to 1, then 1 to 60 back to 1, etc. etc.):

```
         Load  Displacement
0    0.100000           1.0
1    0.101000           2.0
2    0.102000           3.0
3    0.103000           4.0
4    0.104000           5.0
..        ...           ...
391  0.000006           5.0
392  0.000005           4.0
393  0.000004           3.0
394  0.000003           2.0
395  0.000002           1.0
```

Comment: It's gonna be a lot easier to answer your question if you include a sample data.

Comment: Included some simple sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
col = df['B']  # replace with the appropriate column name
# find local minima. FIXED: use rightmost min value if repeating
minima = (col <= col.shift()) & (col < col.shift(-1))    
# create groups
groups = minima.cumsum()

# group
df.groupby(groups).whatever()  # replace with whatever the appropriate aggregation is
```

Example, count values:

```
df.groupby(groups).count()                                                                         

Out[10]: 
    A   B
B        
0  11  11
1  10  10
2   6   6
```

Comment: When I parse into csv files after the groupby() only one csv file is outputted: the original file itself.

Comment: @ephemeralhappiness sorry, I do not understand this comment. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I don't get the your line df.group(groups).whatever()

Comment: Oh that makes sense...I updated my question with a different data set. The y-axis is the Displacement column, but the code does not work for this particular set.

Comment: @ephemeralhappiness there is no visible local minima in the second set

Comment: Sorry, I will include the in-between data.

Comment: The Displacement column essentially goes from 1 to 50 then back down to 1. Then it will go from 1 to 70 then back down to 1. Then it will go to 60 then back down to 1, etc. etc. Would you still like me to write it out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219921/discussion-between-marat-and-ephemeralhappiness).

Comment: It worked! I was struggling with the duplicate minimum the entire time. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

We can try with `scipy` , `argrelextrema`

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
idx = argrelextrema(df.col.values, np.less)
g = df.groupby(df.index.isin(df.index[idx[0]]).cumsum())
```

Comment: How do you know what column is being looked at for the local minima? If my DataFrame has 5 columns, but I'm looking at the graph of columns 1 & 2 plotted against each other, how would I specify that?